# Java multi-thread sockets receive data only once

Tags: java, sockets

I have to do a project in Java for an exam which has to have multi-client sockets.

We have some example code for sockets from our teacher - and I modified it a bit. The problem is that it only receives data once, and then it stops. I found that out by printing the received data into the console.

So here's my the code:

Server.java

```
package socket;

import database.models.PersoanaEntity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static final int PORT = 27015;

    public void start() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
                Socket clientSocket = null;
                boolean isClose = false;

                System.out.println("Server is running");
                while (!isClose) {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    new Thread(new ServerThread(clientSocket)).start();
                }
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

ServerThread.java

```
package socket;

import database.models.PersoanaEntity;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerThread extends Thread{
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ObjectInputStream in = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    PersoanaEntity loggedInPerson = new PersoanaEntity();

    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            //For receiving and sending data
            this.in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String received = this.in.readObject().toString();
            System.out.println(received);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(received);
            execute(received);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void execute(String message) {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(message);
        ProcessInput pi = new ProcessInput();
        pi.processInput(jo, this.out);
    }
}
```

ProcessInput.java

```
package socket;

import database.daos.PersoanaDao;
import database.models.PersoanaEntity;
import jakarta.persistence.NoResultException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Optional;

public class ProcessInput {
    void processInput(JSONObject data, ObjectOutputStream out) {
        switch (data.get("type").toString())
        {
            case "LOGIN_USER":
                PersoanaDao persoanaDao = new PersoanaDao();
                String username = data.get("username").toString();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    PersoanaEntity persoanaEntity = persoanaDao.get(username);
                    json.put("status_code", "200");
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    json.put("status_code", "404");
                }
                try {
                    out.writeObject(json.toString());
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I won't add the code from the client side because I'm quite sure the problem is from the server after doing some tests. I think that it happens because the run method is only called once, AFAIK, and that is when .start() is called from the Thread.

Then it won't ever be called again so there will never be data in the received string.

Am I right?

If so, what's the fix?

If not, why am I getting data only once and how can I fix it?

//edit: I will add the client just in case:

```
package socket;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public enum Client implements Runnable {
    INSTANCE;

    public static final int PORT = 27015;

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public ObjectInputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    public ObjectOutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return outputStream;
    }

    private Socket socket = null;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
    private String name;

    Client() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
            this.outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            this.inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection error");
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Client socket running");

        //For receiving data
        boolean isClose = false;
        while (!isClose) {

            }
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When a "thread" is started using `start()`, its `run()` method is invoked. And if you return from that `run()` method, the thread is done and terminated. So usually threads have a loop inside the `run()` method to perform repetitive or continuous actions. Your `ServerThread` is not doing that and only reads from the socket once.

Comment: @murtiko I expected that - this is what I wrote in the post too :) but what would be a fix? Just a while loop which wraps the try catch in run?

Comment: :) sorry, i have noticed it now. yes, why don't you try that and see what happens?

Comment: @murtiko yes. It works perfectly now. Thanks for your confirmation, you can add that as an answer, I'll accept it asap.